# quadratic objective function with linear constraints.

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

What are the efficient methods for solving quadratic objective function with linear constraints.

Comment: Many commercial solvers have good, well-tested, large scale, convex QP solvers (e.g. Cplex, Gurobi, Mosek).

Comment: "Best" in what way?

Answer (score 1):

That's an impossible question to answer. Commercial solvers include an array of implementations, as "best" depends on the problem structure, size, sparsity, numerical properties etc. Primal-dual (or primal or dual) active-set and interior-point methods are typical generic choices.